# Why $\mathbb E[W\boldsymbol 1_{\{T=k\}}]=\mathbb E[W\mid T=k]\cdot p\{T=k\}$?

Tags: probability

Why $$\mathbb E[W\boldsymbol 1_{\{T=k\}}]=\mathbb E[W\mid T=k]\cdot p\{T=k\}\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of conditional expectation given a random variable $X$ and a conditioning event $H$ is:

$$E[X|H] = \frac{E[X1_{H}]}{P(H)} $$

So just rearrange that definition with W and H being your indicator event. Here we assume $P(H)>0$

---

I suppose you could also prove it this way if S is your sample space:

$$E[X|H] = \sum_{s \in S} X(s)P(\left\lbrace s \right\rbrace |H) = \sum_{s \in S} X(s)\frac{P(\left\lbrace s \right\rbrace, H)}{P(H)} = \sum_{s \in S} X(s)\frac{1_{H}(s)P(s)}{P(H)} = \sum_{s \in S} X(s)\frac{1_{H}(s)P(s)}{P(H)} = \sum_{s \in S} \frac{(X(s)1_{H}(s))P(s)}{P(H)} = \frac{E[X1_H]}{P(H)}$$